# Elasticsearch в java, как добавлять и удалять параметры?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

Я пишу java web spring бэкенд приложение, которое будет обращаться к внешнему серверу. На том сервере, к которому я буду обращаться используется elasticsearch поэтому на своей стороне, я должен сформировать dsl запрос и отправить данный запрос дальше. Следовательно я не могу использовать spring data для составления dsl запросов. Мне прислали, как должен выглядеть пример dsl запроса, и я с помощью библиотеки `org.elasticsearch` пытаюсь написать похожий запрос. У меня почти получилось:

```
        QueryBuilder test = QueryBuilders
                .boolQuery()
                .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("useId.value", 922337203685477580L))
                .filter(QueryBuilders.nestedQuery(
                        "registrations",
                        QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(QueryBuilders
                                        .rangeQuery("registrations.endDate.value")
                                        .gte("now-1y/d")
                                        .lt("now+1d"))
                                .should(QueryBuilders
                                        .boolQuery()
                                        .mustNot(QueryBuilders
                                                .existsQuery("registrations.endDate.value")
                                        )
                                ),
                        ScoreMode.Max))
                .filter(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("user.personalData.lastName.value", "*ф*"))
                .filter(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("user.personalData.firstName.value", "*и*"))
                .filter(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("user.personalData.middleName.value", "*о*"))
                .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("user.personalData.birthDate.value", "2021-11-25"))
                .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("user.personalData.gender.value.code", "C25"))
                );
```

Сам код гораздо больше и содержит гораздо больше вызовов метода filter().
Очень похоже на ужасный код, однако на выходе получаю, почти то что мне нужно.
1)Однако, в каждом фильтре, я получаю дополнительное значение: `"boost" : 1.0` Как мне избавиться от этого?
2)В примере который мне прислали, запрос начинается с

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
...
        }
    }
}
```

А мой результат начинается с

```
{
    "bool": {
...
     }
}
```

Как мне создать сначала объект query, а уже потом в нем bool? Не могу найти информацию в оф документации=(
3)Мне нужно передать значения для пагинации, сортировки, фильтрации и направления сортировки. Как добавить эти значения в данный запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `boost=1.0` означает по факту "ничего не делать с весом" и не влияет на результат
2. Видимо, так:

   SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
   searchSourceBuilder.query(test);
3. У `SearchSourceBuilder` [есть](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.15/java-rest-high-search.html) методы `from`, `size` и `sort`

Comment: СПАСИБО ВАМ, ЗА ТО ЧТО ВЫ ЕСТЬ и за потраченное время! Спасибо Вам большое!